# не перелистывается изображенеи(слайд#js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

я только начал изучать js) я понимаю что вы профессионалы.
у меня есть три картинки для слайда. первая и вторая пролистывается при нажатии на кнопку, а третья нет. Хотя в консоле счетчик изменяется. Быть может условие не правильное. help!!!

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrap">
     <img src="hockey1.jpg" alt="avangard" class="high">
     <img src="hockey2.jpg" alt="spartak">
     <img src="hockey3.jpg" alt="shark">
     <img src="img1.jpg" alt="images">
     <img src="img2.jpg" alt="images">
     <img src="img2.jpg" alt="images">
   </div>

   <div class="buttons">
     <button class="btnLeft" id="btnLeft"> left </button>
     <button class="btnRight" id="btnRight"> right </button>
   </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

`
`
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f9f5c2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.high {
  z-index: 5;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #404af9;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1000ff;
  transition: .5 ease;
}

`
let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); //array images
let left = document.getElementById('btnLeft'); //left button
let right = document.getElementById('btnRight'); //right button
let i = 0; // counter

// events left button
left.addEventListener('click', function(){
  ++i;
  if (i >= images.length){
    images[0].classList.add('high');
    images[1].classList.remove('high');
    images[2].classList.remove('high');
    i = 0;
  } else if (images[1]){
    images[0].classList.remove('high');
    images[1].classList.add('high');
    images[2].classList.remove('high');
  } else if (images[2]) {
    images[0].classList.remove('high');
    images[1].classList.remove('high');
    images[2].classList.add('high');
  }
});

right.addEventListener('click', function(){
  

});

`
`
```

Comment: на что ты проверяеш в else if()? еше раз прочти про то как он работает условие дойдет до второго else if если в else if(images[1]) будет false а там images[1] то есть всегда true

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй
if (i >= images.length - 1){

Answer (score 2):

У тебя 6 изображений, а не 3. И как написали в комментарии выше, у тебя всегда будет срабатывать второе условие, потом когда i станет равно images.length, сработает первое.
Также выбирать изображения по тегу совсем не корректно, лучше задать им какой-то класс.
И лучше всегда делать универсальное решение, которое будет работать с любым количеством изображений, а не ограничиваться 3, т.к. при необходимости добавления нового, тебе придется дописывать условие.
В данном случае потребуется всего одно условие, это сравнить счетчик с количеством изображений и сбросить его, если оно совпало. Сравниваем с `images.length - 1`, т.к. счетчик идет с 0, а количество изображений считается с 1.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
let counter = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  counter++;
  
  //Пробегаем в цикле по всем изображениям и скрываем их
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].classList.remove('high');
    }
  
  //Проверям счетчик, если он находится на последнем изображении, то сбрасываем
  if (counter >= (images.length - 1)){
    counter = 0;
  }
  
  //Показываем изображение соответствующее счетчику
  images[counter].classList.add('high');
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.wrap img.high {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Кнопка</button>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" class="image high">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200" class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200" class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/200" class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/5/200" class="image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/6/200" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!